# MSAccess and ODBC. Filter dialog doesn't show

Tags: ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2007

I have problem with Microsoft Access Database **connected via ODBC** to Postgresql database. Filter dialog - for filtering data using multiple selectable checkboxes:

[image: Check box screenshot]

doesnt work.

*EDIT: Doesn't work: I'mean there is no checkboxes to select. There is only options for sorting A-Z and Z-A.*

How to fix this? 
I can sort data, I can filter by entering single value, but cant filter by multiple values.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define "doesn't work" -- what exactly happens? And where in the A2007 interface are you using the filter interface? It looks like it's in the plain old datasheet, but it's a little confusing for the English speaker to recognize what with the unfamiliar terminology in your language (which I'm not going to try to guess!).

Comment: I mean, that when I'm clicking "Filter" icon then on the filter dialog there is no select boxes (this boxes from screenshot). There is only "Sort from A to Z", "Sort from Z to A".

Comment: The historical Filter choice in the shortcut menu has always worked that way. You can choose multiple values by typing them, e.g., FirstValue Or SecondValue Or ThirdValue, etc. I assume you're alluding to something that is an A2007 innovation, so I will defer to Albert's answer, as he uses A2007 all the time (and A2010, too).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default setting for Access for that filter dialog to show is set at 1000 records. You can certainly increase it beyond 1000 records.

You also have to turn that option on for ODBC linked tables (This default setting is set so you don’t hurt yourself as you must realize for access to build that cute dialog is has to pull all reocrds).

I don’t have 2007 handy, but in 2010 there is a check box to ENABLE that dialog for ODBC sources. I quite sure that check option exists for 2007 also.

Just click on the office button, then access options (lower right), and then choose current database. Scroll down to the section called

```
Filter lookup options for <you database name>  database.
You see a set of check boxes:
[ ]  Local indexed fields
[ ]  Local non indexed fields
[ ]  ODBC fields
```

So, you can enable all 3, and again using this option on odbc, or no indexed columns will have have a cost in terms of performance. Looking at the above set of options, it’s pretty intelligently thought out.