# Lock fields at table level for linked table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'd like to build the simplest MS Access database possible, to allow users to edit a linked table (it links to a SQL Server table).

I only want users to edit 2 of the 10 fields.

Is there any way to do this at the table level? I know I could do this at the form level, but I'm looking for something really quick and easy. I was thinking perhaps there's some way of doing it via a Validation Rule, but I don't see a way of getting the previous/current value.

The main reason I'd like to do this with a table, instead of a form, is that there is the excel-like feature which allows you to filter the table recordset REALLY easily by right-clicking on the field, and filtering (as long as you have it turned on for ODBC tables, like so [MSAccess and ODBC. Filter dialog doesn't show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364846/msaccess-and-odbc-filter-dialog-doesnt-show)).

@HansUp - thanks for your answer. I think what you described would NOT get me the filtering capability that I have in the table view. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think you can restrict access to fields at the table level. Possibly if you had a VIEW on SQL Server that may provide something not available in Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the users an Access query to limit which columns they can edit.  Use a field expression instead of the field itself for those you don't want them to edit.  And use just the field itself for those you do want them to edit:

```sql
SELECT y.ID + 0 AS [ID], y.text_field & '' AS [text_field], y.date_field
FROM YourTable AS y;
```

In that example, `ID` and `text_field` would be read-only, and `date_field` could be edited.

However, I don't quite understand why you're opposed to using a form for this purpose.  It should be quick and easy to set `Enabled` = False and/or `Locked` = True for any bound data controls for which you don't want the users to change values.  You could create such a simple form starting from the form wizard and then modifying the `Enabled` and `Locked` properties as needed.  It should really take only a couple minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. See above as to why I want a table instead of form (in addition to ease of use). But maybe the query option will work.

Comment: Design the form to open in Datasheet View.  Use `Enabled` = True and `Locked` = True for those controls which should be read-only, `Enabled` = True and `Locked` = False for those which can be edited.  Doesn't the form then support the easy filtering you want?

Comment: You've been an awesome help - thanks so much, Hansup! 

I just didn't know that you could do the same filtering in the form that you could in the table. Using the form is much better.